# Two minimum spanning trees

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, trees, integer-programming, operations-research

I have a problem with this exercise.

Consider a non-oriented graph $G=(N,E)$, with $n=|N|$ and weight $c_{i,j}$ associated to the edges $(i,j)$ in $E$.

1. Consider a vertex $a$ in $N$. Write the ILP model to find two spanning trees of minimum total length, without common edges and such that one of them has the number of edges incident to $a$ exactly equal to 3.
2. Consider now a set of vertices $S$ in $N$. Write the ILP model to find two spanning trees of minimum total length, without common edges and such that they touch the vertices of $S$ in a balanced way: incident edges to every vertex $a$ in $S$ used by one of the two trees cannot be greater than two times of edges used by other tree.

My attempt for the question 1.:let $x_{i,j}=1$ if I choose the edge $(i,j)$ for the tree $T_1$ and 0 otherwise. The same for the other tree $T_2$ with the labels $y_{i,j}$. This is my ILP model:
\begin{align}
&&\text{minimize} \sum_{(i,j) \in E} c_{i,j}(x_{i,j}+y_{i,j}) \\
&&\sum_{(i,j) \in E} x_{i,j} &= n-1 \\
&&\sum_{(i,j) \in E} y_{i,j} &= n-1 \\
&&\sum_{(i,j) \in E(S)} x_{i,j} &\leq |S| -1 && \text{for every $S\subseteq N$} \\
&&\sum_{(i,j) \in E(S)} y_{i,j} &\leq |S| -1 && \text{for every $S\subseteq N$} \\
&&x_{i,j}+y_{i,j}&\le 1 &&\text{for every $(i,j)\in E$} \\
&&\sum_{(i,j) \in \delta(a)} x_{i,j} &=3
\end{align}

where $E(S)=\{(i,j)\in E \,|\, i \in S\, , j \in S \}$ ; $\delta(a)=\{(i,j)\in E \,|\, i =a \text{ or } j = a \}$. The first four conditions are the classic conditions for minimum spanning trees to be connected and without cycles. The fifth condition is the fact that the trees have no common edges.

What do you think? What about the second question?

Comment: What have you tried? I'd also like to point out that the standard terminology is "edge" instead of "side".

Comment: Thank you @DánielG. I will edit with my attempt

Comment: Your fifth condition is not quite right - currently it means that every edge is contained in *exactly* one of $T_1$ or $T_2$ (instead of *at most* one of them). And it's not clear to me what you're summing in the sixth condition.

Comment: As for the second part, I don't think it requires a fundamentally new idea - you just have to figure out how to use linear inequalities to express that the two trees are balanced at a vertex $a$ (and then make repeat this requirement for every vertex).

Comment: Ok, how can I change the fifth condition? In the sixth I want to express the fact that one of them has the number of edges incident to $a$ exactly equal to 3. Maybe is more correct writing the sixth as $\sum_{(i,j)\in\delta(a)} x_{i,j}+y_{i,j}$ ?

Comment: The sixth condition was missing a variable at all, and I corrected it.  I arbitrarily chose $x_{i,j}$.  Using $x_{i,j}+y_{i,j}$ instead would be too weak, allowing one such edge in one tree and two in the other.

Comment: The fifth condition should be $\le$ instead of $=$, and I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made several corrections to your formulation for the first question.  The new constraints needed for the second question are
\begin{align}
\sum_{(i,j)\in \delta(a)} x_{i,j} &\le 2 \sum_{(i,j)\in \delta(a)} y_{i,j} &&\text{for $a\in S$} \\
\sum_{(i,j)\in \delta(a)} y_{i,j} &\le 2 \sum_{(i,j)\in \delta(a)} x_{i,j} &&\text{for $a\in S$} 
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much @RobPratt